# Understanding Fortran extends types and override

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, fortran, overriding

I am trying to understand the object-oriented concepts in Fortran 2003 standards (or later). I have some knowledge in C++ so I think there are some common ideas between these two languages which can help me understand them better.

In C++, the polymorphism is done through class derivation and member function overriding. One defines a "abstract" base class where almost all the virtual functions are defined. Different derived classes contains the actual implementation of them. So other functions just need to program based on the "abstract" class. Then they works for all derived classes.

I think in Fortran, the OOP is done in a similar way but there are some differences. In my opinion, it is needed to define a base type with some virtual functions just like C++. And other functions/subroutines should follow the member function definition in the base type. That's the way of resolving the reuse of the function/subroutines for all extends types.

I don't have a better idea on how to program the idea. Here is my first attempt:

```
type Basis
    integer                                 :: NBasis
contains
    private
    procedure                               :: DoNothing
    generic, public                         :: Constructor => DoNothing
    generic, public                         :: AllocateBasis => DoNothing
endtype Basis

type, extends(Basis) :: GridBasis
    private
    integer                                 :: NGrid
contains
    private
    procedure                               :: ConstructorGrid1
    procedure                               :: ConstructorGrid2
    generic, public                         :: Constructor => ConstructorGrid1, ConstructorGrid2, ConstructorGrid3
    procedure                               :: AllocateGridReal
    procedure                               :: AllocateGridCplx
    generic, public                         :: AllocateBasis => AllocateGridReal, AllocateGridCplx
endtype GridBasis
```

- First, how can I define the "AllocateBasis" in type Basis such that it works like the "virtual function" and all extended types must define their own version of "AllocateBasis"?
- Second, how can I define "AllocateBasis" in type GridBasis? The definition here contains the real implementation of it.
- Third, how can I make "AllocateBasis" in type GridBasis a overload function? i.e. there are real version and complex version and both of them are named "AllocateBasis" with real or complex input allocatable arrays.
- Fourth, NOPASS vs PASS. As I understand, if PASS is set then there is a explicit pointer to the object. But when NOPASS is set, there is no such a thing. So PASS is simplify for clarification?

Comment: My goal is to separate the Solver routine and the basis type. You are right. I'll add an example to my post right away. Thanks for the response:)

Comment: You now have a sensible general answer, easily adapted to your particular case.  And your edit clarifies that you know you don't need to do the base thing everywhere (but is useful here).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First some comments/answers to your questions:

- You can declare a type bound procedure being `deferred`. Then you have to define its signature (interface) only without a specific implementation. The type containing the `deferred` procedure must be declared `abstract`. Such types can not be instantiated. All extending types must provide an implementation for the given procedure, unless they are themselves `abstract`.
- In order to provide an implementation for a `deferred` procedure in an extending type, you just declare the procedure in the extending type and provide an implementation for it.
- You can not turn a public procedure of a given type into a `generic` in an extending type. You can, however, define a `generic` already in the base type and extend it in its derived types.
- The `pass` attribute is set by default, so that the *first* argument of the procedure will be the type instance. You can, however, specify it to make it more explicit. Additionally, you could use it in the form `PASS(ARGNAME)` to specify, which argument (`ARGNAME`) should be the instance. This argument needs not be the first one in the procedure.

Below you find a self containing example, which should contain all the features you asked for:

```
module basis_module
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: Basis
    integer :: NBasis
  contains
    procedure(allocBasisR1Interface), deferred :: allocateBasisR1
    generic :: allocateBasis => allocateBasisR1
  end type Basis

  interface 
    ! Interface for real basis allocation
    subroutine allocBasisR1Interface(self, array)
      import
      class(Basis), intent(inout) :: self
      real, intent(in) :: array(:)
    end subroutine allocBasisR1Interface
  end interface

end module basis_module


module extension_module
  use basis_module
  implicit none

  type, extends(Basis) :: GridBasis
  contains
    ! Extending the mapping allocateBasis => allocateBasisR1 of
    ! the parent type.
    generic :: allocateBasis => allocateBasisC1
    procedure :: allocateBasisC1
    ! Implementation for the deferred procedure in Basis
    procedure :: allocateBasisR1
  end type GridBasis

contains

  subroutine allocateBasisR1(self, array)
    class(GridBasis), intent(inout) :: self
    real, intent(in) :: array(:)

    self%NBasis = size(array)
    print *, "GridBasis:allocateBasisR1"

  end subroutine allocateBasisR1


  subroutine allocateBasisC1(self, array)
    class(GridBasis), intent(inout) :: self
    complex, intent(in) :: array(:)

    self%NBasis = size(array)
    print *, "GridBasis:allocateBasisC1"

  end subroutine allocateBasisC1

end module extension_module


program test
  use extension_module
  implicit none

  type(GridBasis) :: mybasis
  real :: myRealArray(10)
  complex :: myComplexArray(5)

  call mybasis%allocateBasis(myRealArray)
  call mybasis%allocateBasis(myComplexArray)

end program test
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! Let me digest it for a while. Just curious: Is there a reason that you separate the base type and extended type in different modules or just your programming style?

Comment: It is just my programming style to use for each type with type bound procedures a different module.

Comment: @Bálint-Aradi, I know this is a dated thread but did this bit of code ever run? It generates a LNK2019 error under IVF 2012 related to symbol "_allocBasisR1Interface" and I lack the necessary knowledge to fix it.

Comment: @IronX yes it does. I've just tried with gfortran 8.2.