# Fortran equivalent to a C++ pure virtual method

Tags: fortran

In C++, I can define a generic interface by

```
class super_class {
public:
    virtual void method()=0;
};

class sub_class : public super_class {
public:
    void method() {
        // Do Something
    }
};

main() {
    super_class *a = new sub_class();
    a->method() // This will call the method defined in the sub_class.
}
```

How do I do the same thing in Fortran? I attempted

```
MODULE super_class
TYPE, ABSTRACT :: super_class_type
END TYPE
END MODULE

MODULE sub_class
TYPE, EXTENDS(super_class_type) :: sub_class_type
CONTAINS
   PROCEDURE :: method
END TYPE

INTERFACE subclass_type
    MODULE PROCEDURE construct_subclass_type
END INTERFACE

CONTAINS

FUNCTION construct_subclass_type()
CLASS (subclass_type), POINTER :: construct_subclass_type
ALLOCATE(construct_subclass_type)
END FUNCTION

SUBROUTINE method(this)
CLASS (sub_class), INTENT(in) :: this
!  Do Something
END SUBROUTINE

END MODULE

PROGRAM example
CLASS (super_class_type), POINTER :: a

a=>construct_subclass_type()
CALL a%method()

END PROGRAM
```

but I end up with a compiler error.

```
CALL a%method(3)
       1
Error: ‘method’ at (1) is not a member of the ‘super_class_type’ structure
```

I'm not sure how to specify that the super_class expects a method to be overridden by the subclass method.

**Tried Using Deferred.**

I tried specifying the method as deferred in the super_class

```
TYPE, ABSTRACT :: super_class_type
CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE, DEFERRED :: method
END TYPE

ABSTRACT INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE method(this)
        CLASS (super_class_type), INTENT(inout) :: this
    END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE
```

but this brings up a new error

```
PROCEDURE, DEFERRED :: method
                  1
Error: Interface must be specified for DEFERRED binding at (1)

CLASS (super_class_type), INTENT(inout) :: this
                       1
Error: Derived type ‘super_class_type’ at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

Comment: Do you mean like a _deferred_ type-bound procedure, such as found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19390401/3157076)?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling the program you have given use? The three letter string "set" doesn't appear anywhere in the program presented

Comment: The presented program is a reduced example of the actual program I'm trying to compiler. set is the equivalent to method.

Comment: Please show the error from the reduced program and edit your question appropriately

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25410476/3157076) and its answer useful.  Your error with `deferred` is because you need to specify the interface (using `procedure(method), deferred ...`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple to fix your last code

```
TYPE, ABSTRACT :: super_class_type
CONTAINS
    PROCEDURE(method_interface), DEFERRED :: method
END TYPE

ABSTRACT INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE method_interface(this)
        import
        CLASS (super_class_type), INTENT(inout) :: this
    END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE


end
```

You should not confuse the name of the binding and name of the interface. I renamed the interface to make it clear. Note the `import` statement needed to get the locally defined names into the interface.